# Cannot install HAXM for Android on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, hyper-v, haxm

I have an Asus ROG Laptop.
at the boot setup, I see the option for virtualization
[image]

In the system, Hyper-v is disabled, by unchecking the features and running `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` at **PowerShell**.

[image]

but yet I get the installation Error

[image]

And also I should mention that `Intel Processor Identification Utility` App is showing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment, but do you have avast or other antivirus software, sometimes it interferes with hyper v.
Otherwise, you could disable and reenable vtx again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable `VT-x` (virtualization technology) and enable feature `XD` (Disable Execution Bit) in the UEFI/BIOS... then it should be possible to install `HAXM` and use it. one can get there, by pressing `DEL` or `F2` before the boot beep (the key may vary, depending on the mainboard vendor).

I've just seen the screenshot; enabling CPU feature `XD` should solve the issue.

Comment: But there is only 3 options that you see at first picture. So I should disable VT-d? There is nothing XD

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi just see your main-board manual, how to enable XD. this might be on another screen, possibly tacked away somewhere, but it should exist... both features need to be enabled, that's the precondition to run HAXM. https://www.asus.com/us/support/ for the manual.

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/78930/Intel-Core-i7-4710HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz ...says Execute Disable Bit: Yes. but the BIOS also needs the option to change the state; cannot provide the manual, because there are many Asus ROG notebooks. which model does the product label say, on the bottom of it?

Comment: https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html might also provide some details. because it appears a little strange, that the BIOS tells the opposite of that what appears to be an Intel info tool... if it cannot be enabled, this might even be a hardware defect - or the BIOS might need an update to enable it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I activated another feature windows hyper version platform. But so slow and incompatible with SDK adb.

Comment: My finla solution, moving to Ubuntu :)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi `KVM` won't run without `VT-x` and `XD` either. better tell me the model and the BIOS revision number. because if updating that does not help, you should request an RMA number and get a replacement machine. Asus has a three years warranty (at least on the parts which I have).

Comment: the problem here is not the `OS`, but it's the `BIOS`, which is either not setting the settings or reporting them wrongfully; therefore switching the `OS` will change nothing.

Comment: I do not have any problem with KVM in Ubuntu, it is installed and usable  Sdk/tools/ emulator -accel-check

Comment: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version --> G56JK.202  in the ASUS site it was the latest version provided

Comment: And also the laptop model is the same ASUS ROG G56JK

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi it's indeed the latest version and I could not find anything that would hint for `XD` in the `BIOS` screenshots. there are two possible reasons to it: a) it's some consumer electronics main-board with a high-end CPU (nevertheless CPUID should tell VT-x & XD settings) b) it's a hardware defect.
contact Asus support in order to request RMA. https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?4806-ASUS-Worldwide-RMA-Guide - they also could reliably tell you if this is a) by design or b) a defect.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will ask them

Answer (score -2):

Intel HAXM requires the Android SDK to be installed (version 17 or higher). For more information, refer to the Android developer website [(https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Comment: Not true. It can be acquired here, standalone: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases
Intel HAXM is an Intel technology, not an Android technology.